# Showing all rows data related to group by match while using group by

Tags: mysql, group-by

I want to select all the photoes avoiding gallery name repetations.But using group by,I retrieve  all the gallery names but I get only one photo related to every gallery.becoz group by only display only one row.

How can I display all the photoes with out repitation of gallery name?ANy alternative approach?.Plz help.

```
$sql=mysqli_query($db3->connection,"SELECT  *   from photo  group by   gallery_name ");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $pic_name=$row['p_name'];

        $gallery_name=$row['gallery_name'];
        echo "$gallery_name>$pic_name,";
    }
```

ANd second alternative approach can be like here but I am still getting gallery name repitation

```
 $sql=mysqli_query($db3->connection,"SELECT gallery_name   from photo  group by   gallery_name ");
        while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)){
            $gallery_name=$row1['gallery_name'];

        $sql=mysqli_query($db3->connection,"SELECT  *   from photo where gallery_name='$gallery_name' ");
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            $pic_name=$row['p_name'];

            $gallery_name1=$row['gallery_name'];
            echo "$gallery_name>$pic_name,";
        }}
```

Comment: Which photos do you want to select for each grouped `gallery_name`? The last one? the first one?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear -- are you trying to order by your gallery names?

Comment: @sgeddes,no I am grouping gallery name and  fetching all the  related  pictures

Comment: Ok -- I've updated my answer -- you need to use DISTINCT and ORDER BY I believe.  Good luck.

Comment: @AanaSaeed You can't `GROUP BY gallery_name` and select all the pictures with it, you have to choose one of them for each grouped gallery_name.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal,exactly,but I want all the gallery names with out repetations and then showing alll the pictures related to each  gellry name

Comment: @AanaSaeed You can't do this in the same query, you will have to do two separate queries one `SELECT DISTINCT gallery_name FROM photo'` this will give you a list of the galleries names without any repetitions. Then use another query to get all the pictures for a specific gallery name using only a `WHERE` clause without any `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal I have upated this in my  question as second alternate ,but still getting reputation.Plz review

Comment: @AanaSaeed Do you mean the second `while` give you repeated photos? if so use `DISTINCT`. Instead of `SELECT  *   from photo where gallery_name='$gallery_name' ` try this: `SELECT DISTINCT * from photo where gallery_name='$gallery_name' `. But you shouldn't echo the gallery name inside the `while` loop this will print the gallaery name multiple times, echo it outside of the `while` loop so that it prints only one time not mutiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for all pictures for a specific gallery, use a `WHERE` clause without group by like this:

```
  SELECT  *   
  from photo  
  where gallery_name  = '$gallery_name';
```

Comment: ,I also  did this as seen in my updated question but still getting reputation of gallery name.

Comment: @AanaSaeed This is because you are printing it inside the `while` loop, print it outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `'ORDER BY'` instead of `"GROUP BY"`.

```
SELECT *
 ...
GROUP BY ...
```

is wrong. Groups are used for counting, finding minimum and maximums, and other group action.
The rest should depend on your PHP code.

Comment: no,I am grouping gallery name and fetching all the related pictures.order by will just sort the pictures accordingly

Comment: ,thank u,I have updated this to my above question as second approach  but still getting the repetition of gallery name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
SELECT  gallery_name, p_name   from photo group by gallery_name, p_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking to use the `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY` keywords:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p_name, gallery_name
FROM Photo
ORDER BY gallery_name, p_name
```

Good luck.

Comment: Then that would involve changing your php code :)  Add logic to check if curr = prev and display accordingly...